# How to Group by a field and Sum another field in codefirst?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of stock model that include 2 field.for example.

**stock model**

```
public class stock
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string product{get;set;}
   public decimal stock{get;set;}
}
```

[image]

I want group by product and sum stock in code first by linq.any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a collection of these `Stock` objects, you can use the [`Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) method along with [`GroupBy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`Sum()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum(v=vs.100).aspx) to retrieve what you are looking for :

```
// This will group each of your elements by their product value and project each of these
// groups to an object that stores the product and the sum of the stock properties for that
// group.
var totals = products.GroupBy(p => p.product)
                     .Select(p => new { Product = p.Key, Stock = p.Sum(x => x.stock) })
                     .ToList();
```

You can [see a working example using your provided input here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nXryow).